# In SQL is it possible to create a serial primary key that begins with a specific letter and is followed by a specific amount of numbers?

Tags: sql, postgresql, primary-key, primary-key-design

I have many lines of existing data which seems to use a unique identifier column that begins with the letter K and is followed by 8 or 9 random numbers. I would like to use this column as the primary key in a table. For all future additions to the table I'd like to automatically generate a unique PK that follows the same format as the existing data. Is there a way to achieve this within SQL code, or would I need to create an elaborate (for my beginner level) Python function that generates the unique PK?

Comment: Is there enough room above the highest number currently used after the K to leave enough room for all the future records you expect? Does the format of new primary keys have to conform to the current keys' format (ie could new keys be all numeric)? Are you allowed to change the primary key values to be just the numeric part?

Comment: There is no text type that auto increments. However, you could create a `sequence` to generate unique numbers and set it to start from 1 + the current highest number used and have the trigger set the key to `K` followed by that generated number.

Comment: @Bohemian while it wouldn't be ideal to have the format of the new PKs not conform to the format of the old PKs, given this specific usecase is simply an exam project and not a database that will eventually have to communicate with other databases, then I guess format conformation isn't strictly required.
I actually tried this first, but couldn't insert the current varchar keys into a serial PK column. It would expect an integer but get a varchar and return an error. Is there an easy fix for this?

I don't think removing the non-integer parts of the current PKs would be acceptable, sadly :(

Comment: I take 8 or 9 random numbers to mean 'a  number with 8 or 9 digits'. this will give you 1 billion ids to play with. I am not aware of any algorithm that can guarantee unique number generation within that. I think you will get 'collisions' (ie the same id would be generated, and you have to re-generate.

Comment: @MyErrorsRunethOver even in an exam it would be better to use a separate autogenerated key and use the text "key" as a surrogate key - a column only used for searching. You'd avoid duplicating this long string in any foreign tables too. A 32-bit (4 byte)integer is large enough for 2Bn rows. The string you have right now takes 10 bytes.  Never mind ordering issues that may arise.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos unfortunately the existing data in 2 foreign tables also include the long K followed by 8 or 9 digits key. It is necessary to use that key to combine the tables. I am considering ditching the key from the other tables in favour of the SERIAL PK that I've already set up as a temporary solution to this problem. However, that would require conversion from the former to the latter at the point of import for the data in the 2 foreign tables. It's doable, but more work with the chance of another hours long troubleshooting process. I've already had way too many of those :(

Answer (score 0):

I would leave the existing rows as they are and continue with a different scheme for future rows, for example a plain number without letter (cast to a string). That can be generated with a sequence conveniently, and there is no risk of collisions.

Simplicity over perceived beauty!

Comment: The question doesn't say that the data is already in a database or that the OP wants to keep using the same table if it is. If a new table is used, the "key" column should probably be treated as just another unique column, with a separate autogenerated key used as a PK.

Comment: Retaining the text values would cause ordering problems too. All numeric values would appear *before* any text values. New values would have to start with eg `Z` to ensure proper ordering. This would cause problems in paging, windowing queries

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Perhaps I wasn't clear enough: I would of course continue to use the same primary key column, only have the new entries in a different format. About ordering: you typically don't need primary keys to be in a certain order, but there is nothing that keeps you from using an `ORDER BY` clause that sorts old entries before new ones.

Comment: Thanks, @LaurenzAlbe. I have no experience with SQL sequences as it was outside the scope of my curriculum this semester. Therefore, when looking into sequences as a possible solution I was scared off fairly quickly. I might pick this back up once I've finished designing a working database and feel better prepared to invest the necessary time.

As for possible ording problems: I'll be displaying the data through a HTML and CSS UI, so their order in the DB is of little importance, fortunately.
Thanks again for both of your inputs!